# Finding the cumulative distribution function given density function

Tags: probability-distributions

I have this statement:

Let $f$ the probability density function of the continuous random $X$ defined by:

$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
\frac{x}{8} & 0≤x ≤4\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$

My current development is:

$
F(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
1 &  x >4\\
0 & x \leq 0\\
?&  0≤x ≤4
\end{array}
\right.
$

I only need the $F(x)$ between $0 \leq x  \leq 4$, but i don't know how to solve it.

PD: I can't use calculus to solve it, so, how could I do it then?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need calculus if you know how to calculate the surface area of a triangle.

Per definitionem, the pdf tells the probability that a random variable falls into an interval by its surface area below the pdf and above the interval.

See our pdf below:

[image]

The cdf at an $0\leq x \leq 4$ qives the following probability

$$P(X\leq x)=\text{the area of the red triangle} =\frac{x^2}{16}.$$

(And of course, for $x$'s below $0$ the cdf is zero and above $4$ the cdf is $1$ which is the surface area of the full triangle.)